# Could I add a potentiometer to a dremel?

Tags: potentiometer

I bought a cord Dremel a while back for some of my personal projects and it seems to speed up after a minute and the rotary bit I like begins to jump and chips pieces away. I haven't sliced the cord but I am assuming it has the standard white,black, and green wires. I would surely have to add a resistor somewhere in the line. Just wanted to check and see if this would be doable?

Comment: Maybe. Maybe not. We can't see inside your Dremel or its wires either.

Comment: I was thinking of adding it directly into the power cord.

Comment: You can find speed controls that will let you control the speed of a dremel. Adding a resistor could conceivably work, but it would have to be sized appropriately and it would likely get hot.

Comment: See http://m.harborfreight.com/router-speed-control-43060.html

Comment: @Majenko You post some really good informative and well thought out answers and some good comments too. And you post some annoying comments like the one above which essentially just says "I don't know", and there is an equivalent form for just about any question anyone could ask. If you stuck to your superb answers and comments & passed on ones like above your radiance would shine forth even more like the sun and .... :-).

Comment: And if your dremel randomly or even predictably changes speed,  check the brushes. Something might be wrong

Comment: You might use a variac for speed control.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I will look in too all the above mentioned. I did not want to purchase another tool, just a couple bucks worth of trinkets from "The Shack". . .Thanks again all. If anyone else has any knowledge of such mod please share.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Some questions deserve my time and energy in crafting an answer. Some, like this one, which are basically "I have this device I'd like to modify. I'm not going to tell you what it is, or bother to do any preliminary research or investigation whatsoever." don't. They deserve to be closed and a scathing comment left. Hence the scathing comment and the close vote. I guess much of the problem is (at the risk of sounding xenophobic) that British sarcasm doesn't translate well to Americans. Many Americans don't get sarcasm unless it's impaled into their foreheads with a sledgehammer.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon That was sarcasm at the end there by the way :P

Comment: @Majenko Here at the bottom of the world at the edge of the empire and the dawn of every day we have a fine sense of sarcasm - and note that many people seem to mistake rudeness for sarcasm. Maybe if I knew more about Dremels the answer may have seemed a bad one. but it seems reasonable enough to me. fwiw. I have a time honoured and highly useful variable speed Dremel, presumably with a model number, but it has never really occurred to me to wonder about models.  The "check the brushes" suggestion from several people made it worth his time asking, even if the question is OT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a resistor will make the speed regulation with load crappy. You want to actually reduce the voltage, either by a variac or by some kind of phase control, like the variable speed Dremels have.

You got a good suggestion to check the brushes (you don't even have to open the case and they're something like $3 for new ones), and if the speed control (assuming you have one) is faulty, it's about $25 for a new one.

If you do decide to replace the tool entirely, you might want to consider a Foredom.

Comment: Thank you. This model did not come with one factory installed, it was a passing idea and thought to look into it. RadioShack tomorrow :)